# How to recover a result of query mongodb outside of its function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, async-await, mongodb-query

I am a new javascript user and I am looking for a rescuer the result (count) of a memory request.

More precisely, maybe you can comment, put my variable in my conv object

right now my result is [promised object]
I tried with async and promised javascript but I do not understand the logic yet

Thank you so much,

Gabriel

```
                            var conversations = []
                            for (var i = 0; i < conversation.length; i++) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < conversation[i].users.length; j++) {
                                    conv = conversation[i].users[j]                 


                                    async function asyncCall() {
                                        function countUnread() {
                                            filterUnread = {$and:[
                                                {toID: user.properties.chat.id}, 
                                                {fromID: conversation[i].users[j].id},
                                                { read: false }]}
                                            return new Promise(resolve => {
                                                Message.countDocuments(filterUnread, function (err, count) {
                                                    resolve(count)
                                                })
                                            })
                                        }

                                        var count = await countUnread();
                                        console.log(count);
                                        console.log(conv)
                                        resolve(!!!!count!!!!) ;

                                    }
                                    asyncCall();
                                    conv.unread = !!!!I_want_my_count_here!!!!
                                    conversations.push(conv);
                                    resolve(conversations)
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: `await asyncCall()` maybe?

Comment: no because, is not in a async function. And if i create a async outside fonction  i lose my resolve. It's the snake that bites its own tail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing `async function`s and `Promise` constructors makes  the code hard to track and causes problems like this one. Instead only wrap the most low level parts into `Promise` constructors, let tuem resolve to something useful, then compose multiple such Promises using `async` :

```
  const filter = { users: { $elemMatch: { id: user.properties.chat.id } } }

function getConversations(filter) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     Conversation.find(filter, function(err, conversations) {
        if(err) reject(err) else resolve(conversations);
     });
  });
}

function countUnread(user) {
   const filterUnread = { $and:[
       {toID: user.properties.chat.id}, 
       {fromID: user.id},
       { read: false }
   ]};

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Message.countDocuments(filterUnread, function (err, count) {
           if(err) reject(err) else resolve(count);
       });
   });
}


async function composeConversations() {
  const conversations = await getConversations();
  const result = [];

  for(const conversation of conversations) {
    for(const user of conversation.users) {
       const count = await countUnread(user);
       user.unread = count;
    }
    result.push(conversation);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The way I read the question, `conv.unread` should be the sum total of all the unread chats(?) across all users in that conversation, ie, initialise `user.unread = 0`, then `user.unread += count;` in the inner loop.

Comment: Does `result.push(conversation)` not just compose an array identical to `conversations`?